# Cannot modify a WriteBatch that has been committed in Node Js with Firestore

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I can't seem to figure out where I am going wrong, I have tried placing the code in an async function and awaiting for the loop to finish but it somehow keeps committing the writebatch before it's done.

Please could someone shed some light on my code, I don't know where I might not be understanding the process.

What I managed to research was that async function run in the background and allows other code to run, so I need to wait for the async operation first if I need a job to be done after.

Please let me know what I'm missing, appreciate the help, here's my code:

```
getReady();

async function stage1() {

    const batch = db.batch();


    await response.data.matches.forEach(async match => {


        var batchRef = db.collection('matches').doc(`${match.id}`);

        var utcDate = `${match.utcDate}`; // ISO-8601 formatted date returned from server


        var localDate = moment.utc(utcDate).toDate();

        var unixTime = ((localDate.getTime()) / 1000);

        const now = new Date();
        const secondsSinceEpoch = Math.round(now.getTime() / 1000)

        var howLong = timeDifference(unixTime, secondsSinceEpoch);


        var checkMatches = db.collection('matches');
        matchesSnapshot = await checkMatches.where('matchId', '==',
            match.id).get();


        if (matchesSnapshot.empty) {


            batch.set(batchRef, {
                competitionName: `${match.competition.name}`,
                competitionId: `${match.competition.id}`,
                matchStatus: `${match.status}`,
                matchDate: `${match.utcDate}`,
                matchDay: `${match.matchday}`,

                unixDate: unixTime,
                matchId: `${match.id}`,



                lastUpdated: `${match.lastUpdated}`,
                homeTeamScore: match.score.fullTime.homeTeam,
                awayTeamScore: match.score.fullTime.awayTeam,

                homeWinOdds: `${match.odds.homeWin}`,
                drawOdds: `${match.odds.draw}`,
                awayWinOdds: `${match.odds.awayWin}`,
                matchResults: `${match.score.winner}`,
                matchduration: `${match.score.duration}`,
                fullTimeHomeTeam: `${match.score.fullTime.homeTeam}`,
                fullTimeAwayTeam: `${match.score.fullTime.awayTeam}`,
                halfTimeHomeTeam: `${match.score.halfTime.homeTeam}`,
                halfTimeAwayTeam: `${match.score.halfTime.awayTeam}`,
                extraTimeHomeTeam: `${match.score.extraTime.homeTeam}`,
                extraTimeAwayTeam: `${match.score.extraTime.awayTeam}`,
                penaltiesHomeTeam: `${match.score.penalties.homeTeam}`,
                penaltiesAwayTeam: `${match.score.penalties.awayTeam}`,
                homeTeamId: `${match.homeTeam.id}`,
                awayTeamId: `${match.awayTeam.id}`,
                homeTeamName: `${match.homeTeam.name}`,
                awayTeamName: `${match.awayTeam.name}`,
                category: 'Football'


            });


        } else if (!matchesSnapshot.empty) {


            var checkingMatches = db.collection('matches').doc(`${match}`);
            var doc = await checkingMatches.get();


            var oldTime = doc.data().lastUpdated;


            var utcDate2 = `${match.lastUpdated}`; // ISO-8601 formatted date returned from server

            var utcDate3 = oldTime; //


            var localDate2 = moment.utc(utcDate2).toDate();
            var localDate3 = moment.utc(utcDate3).toDate();


            var unixTime2 = ((localDate2.getTime()) / 1000);
            var unixTime3 = ((localDate3.getTime()) / 1000);


            if (unixTime2 > unixTime3) {

                const reference = db.collection('matches').doc(`${match.id}`);


                batch.update(reference, {

                    matchStatus: `${match.status}`,
                    matchDate: `${match.utcDate}`,
                    matchDay: `${match.matchday}`,


                    lastUpdated: `${match.lastUpdated}`,
                    homeTeamScore: match.score.fullTime.homeTeam,
                    awayTeamScore: match.score.fullTime.awayTeam,

                    homeWinOdds: `${match.odds.homeWin}`,
                    drawOdds: `${match.odds.draw}`,
                    awayWinOdds: `${match.odds.awayWin}`,
                    matchResults: `${match.score.winner}`,
                    matchduration: `${match.score.duration}`,
                    fullTimeHomeTeam: `${match.score.fullTime.homeTeam}`,
                    fullTimeAwayTeam: `${match.score.fullTime.awayTeam}`,
                    halfTimeHomeTeam: `${match.score.halfTime.homeTeam}`,
                    halfTimeAwayTeam: `${match.score.halfTime.awayTeam}`,
                    extraTimeHomeTeam: `${match.score.extraTime.homeTeam}`,
                    extraTimeAwayTeam: `${match.score.extraTime.awayTeam}`,
                    penaltiesHomeTeam: `${match.score.penalties.homeTeam}`,
                    penaltiesAwayTeam: `${match.score.penalties.awayTeam}`,

                });

            }


        }


    });

    return batch.commit().then(() => {


        console.log("im done");
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log('Mac! there was an error while doing the job: ', err);
    });


}




async function getReady() {


            await stage1();
 

        }
```

Comment: Have you looked at https://dev.to/wceolin/cannot-modify-a-writebatch-that-has-been-committed-265f - it seems that "the first time that function runs, it calls batch.commit() and it commits all changes. So, when that function runs again, we get that error because commit was already called for that instance."

Answer (score 6):

What jumps out to my eye is your `.forEach(async match => {` on the 4th line.  `.forEach()` is **NOT** asynchronous - it will **NOT** wait, it will continue through - which is likely why the WriteBatch is being closed before asynchronous operations try to write to it.

At a minimum you will want to use something like `Promise.All(...whatever.map())` (and discard the result, if you wish) to make the entire thing asynchronous.

To be honest, I haven't even looked at anything after that - there may well be other issues.